# Frequently freezing windows system kills me

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer, mouse, scrolling

I don't know it is a virus and still am using quick heal internet security.my problem is that when windows 10 is fully loaded,after some time the system is stuck for a time. Selection by using mouse pointer is not possible.Also the close,maximize,minimize button's of browser and windows explorer are also on a disabled state.When i works on a web page,PDFs,docs mouse wheel icon is displayed and automatically scroll down and up.Also when clicks on a tab that is opened by a new tab from current page is also closed. my searches are increased day by day to resolve this problem but problem never solved.I am experiences this same problem when i using 7,8.1 also.now updated to windows 10 but the problem is not solved.is it a serious problem??can you give me further instructions???

Comment: Have you noticed your HDD usage at that time?

Comment: Does the issue occur in safe mode? Try reducing what starts up as your PC starts and make sure nothing is scheduled in task scheduler too

Comment: No.is there any problem with HDD drive?

Comment: This problem occurs  when my system starts in a normal mode. Also there is no task scheduled.